# SharePoint 2013 PDFs crawled but not showing in search results

Tags: search

Crawled an external website (not a SharePoint site) containing pdfs. The pdf documents show as being crawled, but some are not displaying in the search results, when searching by content within the document. For example: using the search term "holidays", the document is missing in the results. However, when searching using a  metadata property, "path", the document is visible.

Notes:

- Some pdfs are displayed
- Documents are not duplicates

Any thoughts folks?

Answer (score 2):

Check the type of your PDFs files: many PDF files are either totally or partially image files having originated from scanned documents or faxes.

Sharepoint 2013 indexes only PDF files with text layers, so image PDFs content will not be indexed.